# dotnetcore 3 web api external login with google GetExternalLoginInfoAsync return null most of the times

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi, google-authentication

I have tried almost all possible solutions available online, but still, am unable to get a working solution. I doing a POC with dotnetcore 3 web API, using GoogleAuthentication.

I have configured the returnUrl in console.google as localhost:5432/Account/ExternalLoginCallback

Whenever I try to hit the API at http://localhost:5432/account/externallogin?provider=Google, It hits the ExternalLogin method and then redirects me to google sign-in page, when I sign in, again I am redirected to ExternalLoginCallback method, but signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() mostly return null.

The most surprising thing is that out of 100 tries there are 2, 3 tries in which I actually get data back from signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync().

I am totally confused, can you please help me here

The startup.cs looks like this

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...

            services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie().AddGoogle(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = "<id>";
                options.ClientSecret = "<secret>";
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLoginCallback");

            });
            ...
```

The AccountController has two methods which looks like this

```
[HttpGet("ExternalLogin")]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl="/")
    {
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "Account",
                                    new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        var properties = signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
        return new ChallengeResult(provider, properties);
    }

[HttpGet("ExternalLoginCallback")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        ExternalLoginInfo info = await signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return Content("Could not load user info");
        }
       .....

    }
```

Comment: did you find solution in this problem? we have the same problem

Comment: I have the same problem. I am confused.

Answer (score 0):

### **[Google+ based auth deprecation and replacement](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/6486)**

### ASP.NET Core 2.x

For Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google 2.x the mitigation is to replace your existing call to AddGoogle in Startup with:

```
.AddGoogle(o =>
{
    o.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    o.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    o.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo";
    o.ClaimActions.Clear();
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "id");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Name, "name");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, "given_name");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Surname, "family_name");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("urn:google:profile", "link");
    o.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
});
```

Applications should do immediate testing with the mitigation to check for changes in the data format. Expect a fix for this to be included in the February 2.1 and 2.2 patches that incorperates the above reconfiguration as the new defaults. No patch is planned for 2.0 since it has reached end of life.

### ASP.NET Core 3.0 Preview

The mitigation given for 2.x can also be used for the current 3.0 preview. In future 3.0 previews we're considering removing the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google package and directing users to Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect instead. We'll follow up with the final plan. Here's how to replace AddGoogle with AddOpenIdConnect in Startup. This replacement can be used with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and later and can be adapted for 1.x as needed.

```
.AddOpenIdConnect("Google", o =>
{
    o.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
    o.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
    o.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com";
    o.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    o.CallbackPath = "/signin-google"; // Or register the default "/sigin-oidc"
    o.Scope.Add("email");
});
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();
```